# SSH and Plex Unavailable After Power Outage Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I'm very new to Ubuntu server and have recently set up a server on my home network. It's mainly used for files sharing using Samba and for streaming movies on Plex.

A couple of nights ago I was watching a movie on plex when I lost power at my house. I manually turned the server back on and tried to continue to watch the movie but it said that it was not connected and unable to access the movie on the server. I also tried to ssh via putty from my window machine but it would not connect. Also, I cannot access any of the files that are shared on my network.

I can ping the server and that works and I checked the ufw firewall and everything looks like its right. I'm not sure how to fix this or even where to look.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to this and am trying to learn.

Comment: may be ssh service is not running   try   ** systemctl enable ssh **  on server

Comment: I did systemctl enable ssh and then did systemctl status ssh and it says that ssh is active and running and is listening on port 22. The ufw firewall settings have not been changed and show that OpenSSH is allowed. I also disabled the firewall temporarily and tried to ssh into the server but it still does not work.

Comment: does system have any ips e.g fail2ban ?

Comment: No, the system does not.

Comment: Problem solved. Turns out nothing was wrong with the server. I rebooted the router and shazam everything works as it should!